# too much parsnip and/or parsley flavor

Tags: soup

I made a potato, parsnip (and 1 apple) soup.  I put in a "bunch of parsley tied in a packet."  The soup is too powerful.  I am not sure if it is the parsnip (since I do not typically eat these,) or the parsley.  Any suggestions to "soften" that strong flavor?

Comment: Have you considered separately cooking up another potato or two, puree, and add to the soup?  Alternatively, stirring in a bit of cream might do it.

Comment: For the future: small parsnips and parsley roots can look similar enough to confuse them at the grocery store - maybe that is what happened :)

Answer (score 2):

More potatoes and another apple - dilute (assuming "too strong" is really too strong, and not a just an unfamiliar flavor you would not like even if it was reduced. Parsnips can be polarizing.)

Or add garlic and/or ginger until they overpower the parsnip and parsley (assumes you like garlic and/or ginger...) I guess chili might be another similar approach, but I wouldn't do that as I don't like it. I might add black pepper, though.